# Why "all" parameter gets added in rest web api?

Tags: magento2, rest-api, addtowishlist

I have created wishlist rest web api

from swagger this is something that has been generated as url

```
 localhost/m233/rest/all/V1/wishlistapi/1/2
```

i want to know that ,
Why `"all"` parameter gets added in rest web api ?

Here is my
webapi.xml

```
<routes xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Webapi:etc/webapi.xsd">
   <route url="/V1/wishlistapi/:customerId/:productId" method="POST">
       <service class="Host\WishlistApi\Api\CustomerGreetingInterface" method="addWishlistForCustomer"/>
       <resources>
          <resource ref="anonymous" />
       </resources>
   </route>
   <route url="/V1/wishlistapi/:customerId" method="GET">
        <service class="Host\WishlistApi\Api\CustomerGreetingInterface" method="getWishlistForCustomer"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="anonymous" />
        </resources>
    </route>
</routes>
```

Model file

```
<?php

namespace Host\WishlistApi\Model;

use Host\WishlistApi\Api\CustomerGreetingInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerRegistry;

class CustomerGreeting implements CustomerGreetingInterface
{

    /**
     * @var CollectionFactory
     */
    protected $_wishlistCollectionFactory;
    /**
     * @var CustomerRegistry
     */
    protected $_wishlistFactory;
    /**
     *@var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product
     */
    protected $_productload;
    /**
     *
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
     */
    protected $storemanagerinterface;
    protected $customerRegistry;

    public function __construct(
        CustomerRegistry $customerRegistry,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $_productloader,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storemanagerinterface,
        \Magento\Wishlist\Model\ResourceModel\Item\CollectionFactory $_wishlistCollectionFactory,
        \Magento\Wishlist\Model\WishlistFactory $wishlistFactory

    ) {
        $this->_productloader             = $_productloader;
        $this->_wishlistFactory           = $wishlistFactory;
        $this->_wishlistCollectionFactory = $_wishlistCollectionFactory;
        $this->storemanagerinterface      = $storemanagerinterface;

        $this->customerRegistry = $customerRegistry;
    }

    /**
     * Get customer's name by Customer ID and return greeting message.
     *
     * @api
     * @param int $customerId
     * @return \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException If customer with the specified ID does not exist.
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
     */

    public function addWishlistForCustomer($customerId, $productId)
    {

        if ($productId == null) {
            throw new LocalizedException(__
                ('Invalid product, Please select a valid product'));
        }
        try {
            $product = $this->_productloader->create()->load($productId);
        } catch (NoSuchEntityException $e) {
            $product = null;
        }
        try {
            $wishlist = $this->_wishlistFactory->create();
            $wishlist->loadByCustomerId($customerId);
            $wishlist->addNewItem($productId);
            $wishlist->save();
            return 'ok';
        } catch (NoSuchEntityException $e) {

        }
        return true;

    }

    public function getWishlistForCustomer($customerId)
    {

        if (empty($customerId) || !isset($customerId) || $customerId == "") {
            throw new InputException(__('Id required'));
        } else {

            $collection =
            $this->_wishlistCollectionFactory->create()
                ->addCustomerIdFilter($customerId)->getData();

            $baseurl = $this->storemanagerinterface->getStore()->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA) . 'catalog/product';

            $wishlistData = [];
            foreach ($collection as $item) {
                $productInfo = $this->_productloader->create()->load($item['product_id']);

                $data = [
                    "wishlist_item_id" => $item['wishlist_item_id'],
                    "wishlist_id"      => $item['wishlist_id'],
                    "product_id"       => $item['product_id'],
                    "store_id"         => $item['store_id'],
                    "added_at"         => $item['added_at'],
                    "description"      => $item['description'],
                    "qty"              => round($item['qty']),
                ];

                $wishlistData[] = $data;
            }
            return $wishlistData;
        }
    }
}


Any thoughts on this ?
Thankyou
```

Answer (score 1):

The syntax for Magento rest endpoint is

```
http://<magento_host>/rest/<store_code>/<api_url>
```

Possible values for `<store_code>` could be one of the following:

1. Actual assigned store code
2. **default**: The default value get assigned when store_code is not mentioned.
3. **all** : This specifies that to access all the merchant's stores.

Hope it helps,
Thanks

Comment: How can set if only for default/global in web api ?